# Stack Overflow Jobs pricing

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I've searched high and low and cannot find a price list for posting a job on Stack Overflow. Is there a webpage - ideally one that can be viewed without logging in - that lists the cost of posting a job based in the UK/Ireland?

Comment: I'm almost certain that the pricing was once visible, a vague memory of choosing which country and seeing the price changes springs to mind. I guess that was removed :/

Comment: @DavidG you can see from the screenshot on this page that the pricing definitely was one visible https://recruitee.com/blog/best-job-boards-software-engineers/

Comment: Yes, that's what I remember! Shame it doesn't even exist on the Wayback Machine either :( But at least the screenshot gives you a ballpark for US jobs

Comment: I wanted our company to list on SO but when asked for the cost I had to guess. So I just said "probably a few thousand dollars". They went with Dice instead.

Comment: You were right.

Answer (score 257):

> Is there a webpage [...] that lists the cost of posting a job

**No**, there isn't. Stack Overflow Jobs adopts the pricing model of dinosaur-era Enterprise software sales, where the only way to even *get a price*, let alone *actually buy something*, is to talk to a sales rep.

By contrast, [these people](http://www.spacex.com/about/capabilities) are quite happy to tell the whole world their prices for *launching things into orbit*.

<sub>(source: reading between the lines of [an employee post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351967/71059))</sub>

Comment: This answer would be improved by including the current cost for a geosynchronous orbit transfer, which is slightly over 10$ per g.  (links should be supplimentary, not core to the meaning; and I think it is clear that the exact price that spacex charges at this exact moment is core to this answer)

Comment: I've been considering trying to push my company to advertising a job on SO. I'd be hard pressed with this policy though, "how much does it cost?" "I've no idea you need to ring the sales people", "we'll prob just use the recruitment consultants we normally use"

Comment: Amusingly, if you're considering working for Stack Overflow, you can calculate how much they'll pay you.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but it would be even more useful if it pointed out that the link also contains prices for sending things to Mars.  Literally.

Comment: @Liam Hey look that's exactly how I ended up here! Now I have to decide if I want to potentially overstep my bounds and contact sales myself or try to get HR to wade through the site. I don't like either option.

Comment: I was just quoted this.  They only let you post by the year, and they're super-opaque about it:

Choose Level of Exposure -
(a) Lowest = $3,690 - Gearing active candidates 
(b) Mid = $4,815 - Gearing passive candidates
(c) Highest = $5,940 - Gearing active + passive candidates

For Bay Area, my recommendation is (b) or (c) due to the aggressive competition there, but your choice completely. I will send the link over as soon as you let me know which option.

Comment: Yea it's a definite no when a service doesn't even list a from price. I don't want to get chased by pushy sales people because I just wanted a rough idea of the price of a service.

Comment: I'm surprised Stack Overflow doesn't start requiring people to call them in order to display question answers. Maybe they will in the future at this rate...

Comment: Hmm. Let's see. Have to speak to a salesdroid to get a price or use a site where they have the price up front like SO used to have...

Comment: @bluescrubbie - being quoted thousands of dollars to put a basic listing on a web page is just crazy!!

Comment: Two years ago I posted a job for my company on SO. The prices were public and reasonable (I paid 1200€ for premium access for 6 months). Now things are different. It seems SO have started to get hungry, the last proposal I had was 5700€ for basic offer for 12 months. Wow.

Comment: These prices are crazy. I've seen the same company's job listings for months on SO, so I figured posting on SO must be cheap since they're so ineffective at filling positions (presumably the ad would be taken down once filled). Now I know...

Answer (score 39):

From a sales associate in June, 2018:

> The pricing of our solutions is flexible and completely dependent on your hiring needs over the year. Our baseline package starts at $5699 for the year but again, pricing depends on your hiring needs.

Comment: So if you just want to make one post for one job as a small business you're screwed. cool.

Comment: Compared to agencies though and their fees, this is still good - if you go for an agency, they will supply you with possibly a large number of candidates, but they take a commission from each successful applicant of something like $5000 each time.

Comment: As a small 100% remote company - a starting point over $5000 to post to the community of Devs in Stack for a single job - that kind of pricing model is completely unreasonable. We post in places like Reddit, WorkingNomads, and other places where remote workers are looking - and we use our own social media to spread our web postings. I agree that a tech company like StackOverflow could easily automate and make pricing transparent. You might also get good UX feedback as to where the pricing model leaves many of us looking elsewhere.

Comment: @SublymeRick -- for an extended discussion of this topic please see my question on why SO is inaccessible to small startups: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396467/why-is-stack-overflow-jobs-inaccessible-to-small-startups/396489?noredirect=1#comment765129_396489

Answer (score 29):

I just contacted SO to see if @DevilsAdvocate's answer from June 2018 was still accurate, and it seems to be the case.  As of June 2020 it's still an annual subscription and still starts from US$5k.

Although my employer is a large educational institution, we have so few devs and low turnover that it's difficult to justify spending that kind of money on a couple of job ads a year, especially when we need to have similar arrangements with other job sites to cover all the non-IT recruitment.

At least now I understand why all the jobs on SO seem to be for developer-focused companies.  Only those that focus predominantly on software development can justify the price.  It's unfortunate, as companies that don't have software development as their core business are often really interesting to work for too, as a programmer.

Hopefully one day SO will introduce a lower per-ad rate for smaller companies, so that nonprofits and non-IT companies can also advertise for software developers here too.

Answer (score 9):

You can use third parties such as workable.com, here is the pricing for posting on Stack Overflow:

> [image]

Answer (score -64):

Pricing to post a job ad through Stack Overflow Talent depends on the # of locations you'd like to advertise in, the amount of time you'd like the ad to run for, and the amount of exposure that the ad will get.

Speaking to a sales rep is the most efficient way to ensure you're investing in the right solution that will set you up for success. It's free to speak to a rep, and there is no minimum spend to set up a call.

If you'd like to talk to a sales rep, you can do so [by submitting this form](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/talk-to-an-expert).

(Source: I work with the sales team at Stack Overflow)

Comment: Why not build a form that lets you choose the number of locations, amount of time, exposure, etc. and then shows the corresponding price?

I can't believe this wouldn't be cheaper and simpler in the long run, so I have my doubts about the real motives for forcing people to speak to a sales rep, e.g. so stackoverflow can figure out how much they have to spend and then charge them _that much_.

Sorry, but a lack of transparent pricing is a real personal bugbear.

Comment: If you have to ask, you can't afford it.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Even if someone can afford it, they should still ask about it. This idea that someone should go into a situation without a reasonable or accurate idea of what to expect is not smart at all -for the customer, that is.

Comment: Never was the "This answer is not useful" tooltip on the downvote button more appropriate...

Comment: @AakashM this answer is useful to me, because now I know not to bother searching any further for the prices

Comment: @Dónal don't you mean you don't have to bother looking into this service any further?

Comment: I dislike salespeople and people with an attitude of a salesmen. If I have to talk ask what the price is more than once, I don't buy.

Comment: You lost my business - if you don't want to tell me how much it costs up front and make me work for it then I've lost the inertia to change the practices in the business to use a different tool.

The setup feels sneaky and difficult. I don't want to have to speak on a phone - I can call a recruiter for that! And that's what I wanted to avoid with stackoverflow, which I'd assumed was adopting modern business practices.

Comment: Meredith better get her sales team working on this ASAP -- her reputation depends on it ;)

Comment: Why on earth was this down voted so heavily?  Are people downvoting because they are upset or because the answer is incorrect?

Comment: @ShawnEary The problem is that StackOverflow has deliberately set up the situation that you need to get into a conversation with a sales representative not knowing at all what to expect, allowing the rep to gauge your naivety and charge accordingly. 

How much does it cost to get an ad onto StackOverflow? $500? $5,000?
What's reasonable? What can you expect? 

It's an archaic tool used by sales of old to get as much cash out of a customer as possible.

Comment: @Shawn Eary, the answer is also deceptive and therefor wrong.  It says that it depends on XYZ, but does not mention that there is an annual base price.

Comment: @KevinFinkenbinder - I guess you are right about there being a base price.  I just wish the StackExchange community (in particular the SO crowd) wasn't so brutal...  Thanks for clarifying!!!

Comment: The most efficient way would be to create price calculator right on your website. You can’t even imagine how many potential large clients are not gonna contact sales.