# Cannot request sales rep call to post job listing

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Even though you raised the bar for being able to post job offers on SO by [requiring people to talk to a sales rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351964/87698), I thought I'd give it a try anyways (just because I love SO).

However, after entering my contact details [here](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/de/talent/kontakt), I get this:

[image: error 500]

I also tried calling a sales rep myself by calling the 0800 number posted at the bottom of [this site](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/de/talent/faqs), but it doesn't work. Is it possible that this number only works in Germany? (Hint: There are more German-speaking countries in Europe.)

If you don't want job listings, just say so... ;-)

**EDIT**: Just for the record, my message *did* get through to the sales team (I was contacted and we had a nice chat), so apparently the error occurs *after* the contact data has been forwarded.

Comment: Well... That's embarrassing.

Comment: Explains why the sales reps have had so much free time

Comment: As an aside, it would be handy to be able to post an ad without having to wait to speak to someone... we're ready to post and hire right now but have to wait a week until a sales rep has an 'available slot'.

Comment: *There are more German-speaking countries in Europe* - You mean Italy?

Comment: @Ihazkode: For example. If I'm not mistaken, there are 7 countries where German is (at least regionally) an official language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 500 error you received was an issue with a configuration within our content management system which has since been resolved. Sorry for any inconvenience!

We're working with our German marketing team to resolve the issue with the 0800 number and hoping to get that resolved soon. We'll provide an update once it has been addressed.